# Fontspec - Custom font shape feature

Tags: fonts, fontspec

I would like to be able to add (or remove) a feature from a font shape.

I have read chapter III.3 of the `fontspec` package manual entitled *Different features for different font shapes*. So it is possible to use `BoldFeatures`, `ItalicFeatures` and so on, which solves my problem for these font shapes.

But what if I have defined custom font shapes? For example, I have created a semi-bold font; how can I define something like `SemiboldFeatures` or `SemiboldItalicFeatures`?

Looking for example at the definition of `ItalicFeatures` doesn't help much...

```
\@@_keys_define_code:nnn {fontspec-preparse} {ItalicFeatures}
  {
    \clist_put_right:Nn \l_@@_fontfeat_it_clist {#1}
  }
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{LibertinusSerif}[FontFace={sb}{n}{Font=*-Semibold}, FontFace={sb}{it}{Font=*-SemiboldItalic}]

\begin{document}
firefly \textit{firefly}\quad 
{\addfontfeatures{ItalicFeatures={Ligatures=CommonOff}} firefly \textit{firefly}}

firefly {\fontseries{sb}\fontshape{it}\selectfont firefly}\quad 
{\addfontfeatures{SemiboldItalicFeatures={Ligatures=CommonOff}} firefly {\fontseries{sb}\fontshape{it}\selectfont firefly}}
\end{document}
```

In fact, I need such a feature because I would like to apply kerning in some contexts that would be specific to the semi-bold variant of the font.

However, I suppose it would also be useful in other contexts and with other fonts such as Arial, which has many variants.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that

```
\addfontfeatures{ItalicFeatures={Ligatures=CommonOff}
```

works.

Anyway, you can specify the features you want after stating the `Font`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{LibertinusSerif}[
  UprightFont=*-Regular,
  ItalicFont=*-Italic,
  BoldFont=*-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,
  FontFace={sb}{n}{Font=*-Semibold,Ligatures=CommonOff},
  FontFace={sb}{it}{Font=*-SemiboldItalic,Ligatures=CommonOff},
]

\begin{document}

With ligatures

firefly \textit{firefly}

Without ligatures

{\addfontfeatures{Ligatures=CommonOff} firefly \textit{firefly}}

Without ligatures

{\fontseries{sb}\fontshape{n}\selectfont firefly}

{\fontseries{sb}\fontshape{it}\selectfont firefly}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\addfontfeatures{ItalicFeatures={Ligatures=CommonOff}` is missing a `}`, but otherwise it does work (as can be seen by the example in the question). I think the question was specifically about a way to do this at `\addfontfeature` time and not while declaring the font.

Comment: @egreg thank you for your answer. As @Marcel Krüger says, I would like to be able to do this within a `\addfontfeature` command, as the kerning would not be effective all the time but just in certain contexts where I would then call `\addfontfeature{SemiboldItalicFeatures={...}}`. But after doing some research on the subject, I really don't know how to create a key like `SemiboldItalicFeatures`.